# Improper integral of periodic function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I was given the following question:

> Find all continuous periodic functions $f(x)$ for which the integral $ \int^\infty_0f(x)dx $ converges.

Now, I have a feeling this is only the function $ f(x) = 0$ , yet I have a problem formally proving it.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have the feeling that $f = 0$ is the only one? Can you describe what would go wrong for others?

Comment: Otherwise, the area between the function's graph and the $x-axis$ will not be insignificant, and so keeping accumulating will end in divergence.
...right?

Comment: Depending on what you mean with "accumulating" this is either right or not quite right, but you have identified the essential problem. We have nontrivial area (signed) if $f \not\equiv 0$, and by periodicity that doesn't diminish. Try to work out a proof using Robert's hint in the answer. If you don't manage, feel free to ask for further hints.

Comment: @DanielFischer The integral over a period can be zero without the function being zero though, so it's not just as simple as "the area will keep accumulating" - you also have to prove in the case that ${\int_{0}^{L}f(x)dx=0}$ but ${f(x)\neq 0}$ that it still diverges, right?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $f$ is periodic with period $P$. Find an equation relating $\int_0^{t+nP} f(x)\; dx$ to $\int_0^t f(x)\; dx$ and $\int_0^P f(x)\; dx$.  What does that tell you $\int_0^t f(x)\; dx$ must be?

Comment: So, I got that $ \int^{t+nP}_0 f(x) dx = \int^t_0 f(x) dx + n* \int^P_0 f(x) dx $ but I don't see what could I conclude from this

Comment: Next step: if $\int_0^P f(x)\; dx \ne 0$, would the limit as $n \to \infty$ exist?

Comment: OK! So eventually I disproof the assumption using _Cauchy's test_ (not sure how it is called in English...)